# Typescript + React - Get the type of a variable from its type

Tags: reactjs, typescript, devexpress

New to Typescript and unsure on how to achieve this.

I'm using React to build a component - a table - using this library https://devexpress.github.io/devextreme-reactive/react/grid/docs/guides/getting-started/

Say I have some service that gets some data:

```
const { data, error, loading, refetch } = songService.get(queryOptions);
```

I want to call this service in the table component itself, however I don't want it to be restricted to only getting data from the `songService`. I'd like to get it from whatever service I pass in the props - so I'm thinking:
`<DXTable serviceFromData="songService" />` or `<DXTable serviceFromData="coverService" />`

However I have 2 questions/uncertainties:
- What type would the `serviceFromData` prop be? I'd like it to be generic.
- How do I ensure my `const queryOptions` has a specific interface based on the service?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I would create an interface for each service and have them extend a common interface.
From here you have two options:
 1. `serviceFromData` can take the type of the common interface so it somewhat generic
 2. `serviceFromData` can take a type like `Service1 | Service2`

You can ensure the `queryOptions` to be a specific interface by adding the desired type to the `get()` method like `get(queryOptions:SomeInterface)`in your service classes.